# How to send nottification when work service shut down

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

What is the best practice if I want to send an application insight message to Azure when my Work Service is shutdown.
So I notice that I can't get the message if I insert **telemetry.TrackEvent("Shutdown");** in the StopAsync Function.

```
public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            telemetry.TrackEvent("Shutdown");
            logger.LogInformation("Queued Hosted Service is stopping.");
            await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
```

Comment: One question, can you see the logs that generates by `logger.LogInformation()` method?

Comment: Hi @IvanYang thanks for your reply and sorry for my lated reply, so I notice that when I call Flush() method after telemetry.TrackEvent("Shutdown") an I can receive the application insight logs in Azure